# How can reload the data in table view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with reloading the data in table view controller. When I'm in the main controller and search a record, it's showing the profile details of that record. And when I'm coming back from profile screen the records in the main screen are not showing. It is showing only one record, the one which was selected before.

This is my code:

```
let tempDict:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary();

var cardImg:UIImage!;
if(contactList.card_img_frontside != nil){
    cardImg = UIImage(data: contactList.card_img_frontside)!;
    tempDict.setObject(cardImg, forKey: kCardImgFront as NSCopying);
}
else{
    if let url = contactList.card_img_url{
        tempDict.setObject(url, forKey: kCardImgFront as NSCopying);
        tableView.reloadData();
    }
}

var cardImgBack:UIImage!;
if(contactList.card_img_back != nil){
    cardImgBack = UIImage(data: contactList.card_img_back)!;
    tempDict.setObject(cardImgBack, forKey: kCardImgBack as NSCopying)

}
else{
    if let url = contactList.card_img_url_back{
        tempDict.setObject(url, forKey: kCardImgBack as NSCopying);
    }
}
```

**Main Screen**

[image]

**Profile Screen**

[image]

Click back button on profile screen it is showing like this:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post code for the entire UITableViewController

Comment: It looks very much that you are doing this yourself. Show at least your code in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: It might be that you're overriding your array model during your search and that you weren't working with a copy.

Comment: tableView.reloadData()  ?

Comment: Please check it once @Abhishek Singh

Comment: Please check it once @fishinear

Comment: Is there any alternative for that copy and what is that? Please help me out @Miket25. I am working from one day for this issue.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for why you can copy your data array and search through that while calling `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: I used that one @Miket25. it is working. but the problem is ., it is working in two cases.  1. searching and all the records showing in main controller and the card image is not loading in second controller. 2. searching is working in main controller and click on record it goes to second controller and image is loading and when coming back to main controlle it is showing only records what i searched.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for numberOfRowsInSection...

```
func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    var rowCount:Int?  = 0
    if(tableView == self.menuTableView){
        rowCount = self.menuOptions?.count;
    }
    else if(tableView == self.slideMenuTableView){
    rowCount = self.slideMenuArray?.count;
   }
    else if(self.isSearching == true){

        rowCount = self.filteredArray?.count;
   }
   else {
      if let controller = self.fetchResultController
      {
        let sections :Array = controller.sections!;
        let sectionInfo = sections[0] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo;
        rowCount = sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;

       }
     }
     return rowCount!;
}
```

This is for cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var tableViewCell:UITableViewCell! ;
    if(tableView == self.tableView){
    let cellID : String = "CellIdentifier";
    var cell : MGSwipeTableCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID) as? MGSwipeTableCell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (((Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MGSwipeTableCell", owner: self, options: nil)! as NSArray).lastObject) as! MGSwipeTableCell);
            cell.delegate = self;
        self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath);
        tableViewCell = cell;
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.5
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's original question?

Comment: @Prathap On StackOverflow, if you somebody asks you to show code, you would normally add the code to the question, instead of creating an answer.

Comment: But it does show what is likely going wrong in your case. You probably have `self.isSearching` set to `true`, which causes only the `filteredArray` to be shown.

Comment: Ah didn't notice this was your code to your question. 

Comment: Oh Sorry for that @Miket25 and. I am new to stackoverflow to write the questions.

Comment: when i uncomment those lines of self.isSearching in numberfRowsInSection and run the code i am unable to type and it throught an uncaught exception

Comment: @PrathapReddy I assume this is not your code? You should not remove the code, you should make sure that `self.isSearching` is set to `false`